# Calculating running average with sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using the following code to calculate a running average:

```
SELECT AVG(close) FROM daily
ORDER BY datum DESC
LIMIT 50
```

for a 50-day average. However, it doesn't seem to work. I can change `LIMIT` to `5`, `10`, `20`. The result is always the same. Is the `LIMIT` just a visual limit maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LIMIT` restricts your result set, not the set you're averaging over. You'd want something like

```
SELECT AVG(close) FROM
(
    SELECT close FROM daily ORDER BY datum DESC LIMIT 50
)
```

Comment: yes. but the problem is that the days are not consecutive..there might be some 'holes' in, so it is basically last 50 entries